# internet permission not granted

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I am writing an app to send msg over TCP Socket. I am struggling to get access to the internet permission. (API 26 is the target)

```
socket EACCESS permission denied
```

I have setup in my Manfest :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.seb.sebastien.opengardenirc">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.persmission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
```

As I am using the API26, I have to add a permission check in the code to make sure it works fine:

```
if (shouldAskPermission()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Permission is required");
            String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
                    Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
            };

            int permission_internet = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET);
            int permission_network = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE);
            int permission_wifi = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE);

            Log.d(TAG, "Package Manager: " + PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            Log.d(TAG, "INTERNET : " + permission_internet);
            Log.d(TAG, "NETWORK : " + permission_network);
            Log.d(TAG, "WIFI : " + permission_wifi);

            if ((permission_internet != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    || (permission_network != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    || (permission_wifi != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
                Log.d(TAG, "Asking for permission");
                // We don't have permission so prompt the user
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        this,
                        PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                        REQUEST_CONNECTION_PERMISSION
                );
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission (already) Granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(TAG, "Permission already granted");
                startTcpInAThread("str");
            }

        }
```

And I have also the method to catch the `onRequestPermissionsResult`.

```
private boolean shouldAskPermission(){

        return(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT> Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int permsRequestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults){

        switch(permsRequestCode){
            case REQUEST_CONNECTION_PERMISSION:
                Log.d(TAG, "Permission granted result : " + grantResults[0]);
                Log.d(TAG, "Permission granted result : " + grantResults[1]);
                Log.d(TAG, "Permission granted result : " + grantResults[2]);


                boolean accepted = (grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                        && (grantResults[1]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                        && (grantResults[2]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                if(accepted) {
                    startTcpInAThread("str");
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permissions issues!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;

        }

    }
```

First things is that when checking the permission, I can see that `android.persmission.INTERNET`is not granted. Good thing is that it's going to call the request permission method `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions`

I was expecting a Dialog box showing up but my understanding is that the dlgbox only show up for some on the permission requests some other do not need to ask.

My concerns is that when I got `onRequestPermissionsResult`the permission is still not granted.

Anybody know how to grant the permission to internet ?

I have also pay attention to not run the network access in the same thread.

Regards

Comment: `android.persmission.INTERNET` - You've misspelled `permission` in the manifest.

Comment: thank you. I spent all my time trying to find the error in the java code

Comment: Also note that `INTERNET` is not a `dangerous` permission; you do not request it at runtime.